# How to check if a component is unmounted/destroyed?

Tags: vue.js

Here's a simple scenario. In my component a user sends a request to the server. The component has a callback that runs when the request fails. The error callback shows the user an error message. The problem here is that when the component is unmounted the user still gets an error message on their screen(request takes a long time to return an error). In my case it's not a desirable behavior. So, how do I check if my component is unmounted to prevent the callback from showing the error?

Comment: Can you cancel the call in beforeDestroy? assuming you use axios  https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: @alt146, It's one way to go about it. But I could just as easily added a vm  property 'isDestroyed' and set it to true in beforeDestroy and check it in my callbacks. I don't see any downsides to this compared to your solution.